# Populate Dates from column as Column Names

Tags: sql, pivot

Form the below dataset:

```
Column A | Column B | Column C

Monkey   | 201901   | 100

Donkey   | 201901   | 100

Banana   | 201901   | 100

Monkey   | 201902   | 100

Donkey   | 201902   | 100

Banana   | 201902   | 100

Monkey   | 201903   | 100

Donkey   | 201903   | 100

Banana   | 201903   | 100

Monkey   | 201904   | 100

Donkey   | 201904   | 100

Banana   | 201904   | 100
```

I want an Output like this:

```
Animals | 201901 | 201902 | 201903 | 201904

Monkey  | 100    | 100    | 100    | 100    
Donkey  | 100    | 100    | 100    | 100    
Banana  | 100    | 100    | 100    | 100
```

Comment: Any *particular* SQL query will always produce a result set with a fixed "shape" - the number of columns, their *names* and types. I suspect you're looking for something that doesn't fit the above (you want a varying number of columns and names driven from the data) which means having to construct new queries on the fly (a.k.a. dynamic SQL). Best avoided if you can do this *presentation* work in a more appropriate place (UI application, report builder, etc)

Answer (score 0):

You want *conditional* aggregation :

```
SELECT colA AS Animals, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN colB = '201901' THEN colC END) AS 201901,
       MAX(CASE WHEN colB = '201902' THEN colC END) AS 201902,
       MAX(CASE WHEN colB = '201903' THEN colC END) AS 201903,
       . . . 
       MAX(CASE WHEN colB = '202012' THEN colC END) AS 202012
FROM table t
GROUP BY colA;
```

Comment: What if the Date 2019XX is long like 201901 to 202012?

Comment: @Parithi. . .  Then you would to use `Dynamic SQL` query.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pivot

```
select cola, max([201901]) as [201901], max([201902]) as [201902],max([201903]) as [201903], max([201904]) as [201904]
from tablename
pivot
(max(col3) for col2 in ([201901],[201902],[201903],[201904])
)pv
group by cola
```